# Python Tkinter. Fix attribute error "Event object has no attribute tk" when using binding to create a new window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a menubar and I am trying to create keyboard shortcuts to open these links. The shortcut will run a function that runs a class. This class creates a new window. But I keep getting this error:

```
    AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

I have gone through many answers to problems similar to mine but had no success. I read on multiple answers that an instance of the class needs to be created to which I have done.

What I can't understood is when clicking the link on the menubar it works.
In the TrackComicScreen  class before the bind commands.

Here is a minimised version of my code.

```
    from tkinter import *

    class TrackComicScreen:
        def __init__(self, master):
            self.master = master
            root.bind("<Control-Shift-A>", self.AddNewEntry)

        def AddNewEntry(self, master):
            addComic(master)

    class addComic:
        def __init__(self, master):
            self.AddNewEntryWindow = Toplevel(master)
            self.AddNewEntryWindow.geometry('460x440')

    #WINDOW PROPERTIES
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("1074x714")
    currWindow = TrackComicScreen(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

ERROR Message extract

> ```
> addComic(master)
>
> self.AddNewEntryWindow = Toplevel(master)
>
> BaseWidget.__init__(self, master, 'toplevel', cnf, {}, extra)
>
> BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
>
> self.tk = master.tk
>
> AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'tk'
> ```

The expected result is for when Ctrl Shift A is pressed a new window should appear.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than some disjointed code fragments.

Comment: Hi Bryan, I have added an example above that produces the same error. Thanks in advance

Comment: The example works, at least for me.

Comment: @GreenMatt try the shortcut Ctrl Shift A to open a new window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind a function to a key, the function will be caused with one positional parameter which represents the event that caused the binding.

Consider this code:

```
root.bind("<Control-Shift-A>", self.AddNewEntry)
```

When `self.AddNewEntry` is called, tkinter will call it with one parameter, which is an object that represents the event (eg: `self.AddNewEntry(event)`). This object has properties such as the widget that received the event, the x/y coordinates of the mouse pointer, the key that was pressed, and so on.

You've named this parameter `master` which makes me think you're expecting that code to somehow represent the master or root window. And indeed, you pass that parameter to `addComic`, which then tries to use this event object as the master window for a `Toplevel` window. Since you can't use an event object as a master for another window, you get an error.

While you can modify the binding to pass `master` to the function, since you are storing `master` as an attribute of the class there is no need for you to do that -- `AddNewEntry` already knows what `master` is.

The solution is to rewrite `AddNewEntry` to accept the `event` parameter and ignore it, and pass `self.master` down to `addComic`:

```
def AddNewEntry(self, event):
    addComic(self.master)
```

Comment: thanks it worked. I spent hours trying to fix this. One of the things I tried was changing master to event but I didn't change the master.

Answer (score 1):

The `bind` generates an event when invoked, which is then passed to the callback function. So, in short, you are doing:

```
def AddNewEntry(self, event):
    addComic(event)
```

And the event can't be the master of a `Toplevel`.